# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

```
const list = document.getElementById('generateList');
const listAdd = document.createElement('li');
listAdd.innerText = "Name"
list.appendChild(listAdd)
```

This code returns: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
Why and how do I fix it?

HTML:

```html
<ul id="generateList">

   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Post your html also

Comment: Either the element with ID `generateList` doesn't exist or you're executing the javascript before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I ran the code before DOM was loaded. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code ran before DOM was loaded. I changed into a function and then ran it.

Comment: Timing is always tricky.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error means your `list` equals `null` and you can't call `list.appendChild(...)`.

Log `list` after line `const list = document.getElementById('generateList');` and check it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the same as @TheKidWhoCantCode said

I had buttons:

```js
let div = document.querySelector(".div-buttons");
```

and I solved it just by saving my HTML document, as I think it returned null because in this case there wasn't a div-buttons class until I saved it